# How to load cookies from file for net/http requests

Tags: ruby, curl, cookies

I was recently making use of this: [Send cookies with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181785/send-cookies-with-curl)

I'm now trying to automate the process in a ruby script.

However, I don't see anything native that will load cookies from a file for a given request.

What is the best way to load cookies from a file for net/http requests in Ruby?

Update: I'm just using a browser plugin to dump all my cookies into a file. I'd like to load that file for use as cookies. the curl example would be:
 `curl -b cookies.txt http://example.com` (notice I'm only using '-b').

I'd *really* like to avoid looping through everything in the file and parsing out the cookies and setting headers individually. I'm looking for the ruby equivalent of this python code (ref: [Using cookies.txt file with Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742899/using-cookies-txt-file-with-python-requests))

```
import requests, cookielib

cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar('cookies.txt')
cj.load()
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
```

Comment: I've updated my question to explain the difference in what i'm looking for.