# How to stay logged in by crawler written in python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl some info from a Discuz!(v3.3) website.(http://bbs.guitarera.com/)

I write a file A to login, and save the cookies as a file.
Then I write a file B to login with the cookies saved by file A.

file A worked well.with the respond html, I can search my username(1016zym), means it is working. But then I run file B, which never worked. Can't stay logged by the saved cookies.

Wonder why?

File A: login with username and password

```
import requests
try:
    import cookielib
except:
    import http.cookiejar as cookielib
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.61 Mobile Safari/537.36'

headers = {
    "Host":"bbs.guitarera.com",
    "Referer":"http://bbs.guitarera.com/forum.php",
    'User-Agent':agent
}

session = requests.session()
session.cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar(filename='cookies')
try:
    session.cookies.load(ignore_discard = True)
    print("Cookie loaded")
except:
    print("Cookie not loaded")

def login(account,password):
    formhash = getFormhash()
    print("formhash:",formhash)
    postUrl = "http://bbs.guitarera.com/member.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&handlekey=login"
    postData = {
        'fastloginfield':"username",
        'username':account,
        'password':password,
        'quickforward':'yes',
        'handlekey':'ls',
        'formhash':formhash
    }
    loginPage = session.post(postUrl,data=postData,headers=headers,allow_redirects=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(loginPage.text)
    #print(soup.prettify())
    session.cookies.save()
    print(soup.find(text=re.compile("1016zym")))# could found means successful logged in
    return ""

def getFormhash():
    url = "http://bbs.guitarera.com/member.php?mod=register"
    page = session.get(url,headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    # print(soup.prettify())
    k = soup.find_all(type="hidden")
    r = soup.find_all("formhash")
    pattern = r'name="formhash" value="(.*?)"'
    formhash = re.findall(pattern, page)
    if len(formhash) < 1:
        print("formhash acquire failed")
    return formhash[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("prepare to log in")
    account = '1016zym'
    password = "qwer"# should be md5(password)
    login(account,password)
```

file B: trying to stay logged with cookies

```
import requests
try:
    import cookielib
except:
    import http.cookiejar as cookielib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.61 Mobile Safari/537.36'

headers = {
    "Host":"bbs.guitarera.com",
    "Referer":"http://bbs.guitarera.com/forum.php",
    'User-Agent':agent
}

session = requests.session()
session.cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar(filename='cookies')
try:
    session.cookies.load(ignore_discard = True)
    print("Cookie loaded")
except:
    print("Cookie not loaded")

def isLogin():
    url = "http://bbs.guitarera.com/forum.php"
    t = session.post(url,headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(t.text)
    # print(soup.prettify())
    print(soup.find(text=re.compile("1016zym")))

    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("prepare")
    isLogin()
```

Comment: You will find some useful answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737740/python-requests-and-persistent-sessions and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742899/using-cookies-txt-file-with-python-requests

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by some debugging.

In `File A`,

`session.cookies.save()`

should be

`session.cookies.save(ignore_discard = True,ignore_expires=True)`

This will save all cookies in the file.`save()`will only save not discarded and not expires cookies. Which I happened to need for logging.

In `File B`

`session.cookies.load(ignore_discard = True)`

should be

`session.cookies.load(ignore_discard = True,ignore_expires=True)`

by this two step, you can store/use exactly the cookies you acquire.