# Load cookies txt file in to Python

Tags: python, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to read and load a cookies.txt file saved on my local computer in Python.

But I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

My code looks as follow:

```
with open ("cookies.txt", "r") as text_file:
    yup = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(pickle.load(text_file))
cookies = yup
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here? I downloaded the cookies with the cookies.txt extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cookies.txt file with Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742899/using-cookies-txt-file-with-python-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `rb` `read-bytes`

```
with open ("cookies.txt", "rb") as text_file:
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that. I get the following: EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: @Solaiman do you have something in your file? i think it is empty